# Windows server 2008 foundation

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, data-migration

Can I migrate from windows server 2008 foundation to windows server 2012 r2 ?
My windows server 2008 foundation contains AD DS, Exchange and data of company.

Comment: Yes, it’s done the same way as any other migration.

Comment: Of course you need a license to Windows Server 2012 your Windows Server 2008 license cannot be used